# Photo competition December 2018

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

Over the next three months I want to run a photo competition, (it can run longer if well accepted and active, but three months is guaranteed.)
The highest voted answer will get the fame and bragging rights. An extra virtual prize may be given to that or any other photo.

The basic rules are the same as those for the last competition.

Rules:

- 1 post per answer.
- May submit more than 1 answer per user.
- try and keep it non offensive.
- All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken.
- the photo has to be taken by the user who posted it and taken in the time frame given in the description for that month's photo.

The next rule changes per month, the subject of the picture and its 'when it was taken'.

For the month of December I would like to set the rule:

- The photo is of a building and the angle of taking the photo should be different from the norm.
- The photo can have been taken any time before the end of December 2018, has to have been taken by the person posting the answer.
- The photo should not include people as important part of the picture. If unavoidable, people can be included as long as they are not recognizable.
- No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of December 2018, voting will run till midnight 31st of December and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.*
  Note* If there is no clear winner at the end of voting period, the voting period can be extended.

The subject and dates for the other months have been announced, in a different 'questions'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The underside of the the now almost unused Forth Road Bridge, from South Queensferry (as traffic now uses the Third Firth of Forth Bridge.)

Taken 1 Dec 2018

Comment: Rory, take a bow, most upvoted photo in our December competition.

Comment: Thank you upvoters - and have a Very Happy New Year. May 2019 bring everyone health and happiness.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Looking down on the Atomium in the snow]

([Larger sizes on Flickr](//www.flickr.com/photos/taylor_pj/8256047206/))

Atomium, Brussels. Taken 7th December 2012.

The building was originally constructed for the 1958 World Fair. For people who want to see some other perspectives, I have [a few more](//www.flickr.com/photos/taylor_pj/tags/atomium/) (and obviously there are loads in your favourite search engine's image results), but IMO this one best fits the contest's constraint of an angle different from the norm.

Answer (score 6):

[image: a powerstation chimney, diagonal on the picture.]
The power station in Velsen Noord, the Netherlands.
Photo taken by Willeke, 30 November 2018, photo can be used by all.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Coit Tower]

Coit Tower (follow the arrow) taken from the north side of the Golden Gate Bridge. Taken 31 October 2005.

Answer (score 6):

HSBC Canada Square, London. 3 Dec 2018.

Because lions!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

View looking downward from the [Macquarie Centre](https://www.macquariecentre.com.au/community/macquarie-mall-walkers) upper story, through the art mural to the lower floors.  Photo taken late in 2017.

[image]

Comment: I love the choice of position which gives vanishing points in opposite corners.

Comment: Greg, yours is my personal favorite. You get a 'do it yourself sandcastle on the beach', tools and travel costs not included.

Answer (score 5):

The Patriarchal Cathedral Basilica of Saint Mark, St Mark's Square, Venice, Italy, Oct 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: the Eiffeltower, Paris, France from within one of the legs]

I took this photo of the Eiffeltower 7 April 2015.
I was inside one of the legs.
Photo free to use.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

A better view of the Blarney Stone, Monacnapa, Blarney, County Cork, Ireland (for those of us who don't do hanging upside down at the top of an open tower ... and/or applying lips where millions of others have been before). My photo, taken in September 2015.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Lloyd's building, London, UK]

Lloyd's building, London, UK. Taken 9 April 2009.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Details:
Date: April 2017.
Place: Khidrapur Temple, MH, India.
Device: Lenovo Vibe K4 Note (Mobile), Greyscaled in LightRoom

Answer (score 3):

Eilean Donan Castle, Scotland, 2018

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Details:

- Date: July last week, 2018.
- Place: [Thikse Monastery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thikse_Monastery), India.
- Resolution: 4608 x 3456
- Device: NIKON COOLPIX B500
- No Flash, Focal length 4.0 mm, Aperture f/3.0, Exposure 1/500, ISO 125

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Details:
Date: April 2017.
Place: Khidrapur Temple, MH, India.
Device: Lenovo Vibe K4 Note (Mobile), Greyscaled in LightRoom